# What to do if I have a question, which was allready asked but non of its answers fits my case?

Tags: discussion

title as it says.

Should I in this case anyway ask it again and explain that my case is different in the given paramters?

Or is offering a bounty my only option?

For the second case my impression was so far, people would tend to just ignore the notes for the bounty and especially as it is a highly visited post, they tend to go on voting on purpose of like or dislike and my bount would go to some one who absolutley doesn't deserve it.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a duplicate to answer this, but to give you a quick answer: If you can cite and explain why none of the answers in the question you found fits your case, and make a clear question out of it with all that included, it shouldn't be closed as duplicate. _Do not_ just link to the other question and say it doesn't help you. Be sure to explain _why_ it doesn't help you and why the answers didn't help you.